# error: (-2:Unspecified error) from OpenCV dnn modeule

Tags: opencv, tesseract

I'm trying to run opencv text detection sample [code](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/db/da4/samples_2dnn_2text_detection_8cpp-example.html), but I'm getting bellow run time error from dnn module.

> $ ./textdetect -i test.jpg -m frozen_east_text_detection.pb
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():
>   OpenCV(4.0.0) /home/infy/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:3644: error:
>   (-2:Unspecified error) Cannot determine an origin framework of files:
>   true in function 'readNet'
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

My system configuration:

OpenCV version 4.0
Ubuntu 18.04
Tesseract version 4.0.0-beta.1
Leptonica version 1.75.3

I have downloaded the .pb model file from [here](https://github.com/oyyd/frozen_east_text_detection.pb). Does anyone faced this issue.?

Comment: Try with original net: https://github.com/argman/EAST#download
Or with caffe net from opencv_text: textbox.prototxt + TextBoxes_icdar13.caffemodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Arguments should be passed as below.

> $ ./textdetect -i=test.jpg -m=frozen_east_text_detection.pb